# $(pwd) doesn't resolve properly when running from npm script

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, git-bash, npm-scripts

**The issue:**

`$(pdw)` does not resolve properly when running as part of npm script.

running a script with param including `$(pwd)` in the terminal seems to be working fine though. e.g.:

**Simplified example:**

`package.json`

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "test-pwd": "echo $(pwd)"
  },
  ...
}
```

```sh
# this command works correctly
echo $(pwd)
# output: /c/Users/<User>/path/to/repo

# this commad doesn't work
yarn test-pwd
# output: $(pwd)
```

**my actual code:**

`npx @bazel/bazelisk run //tools/ci:pwd_script_py -- --root-dir=$(pwd)`

^ this works fine

But this is my actual setup:

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "s1": "...",
    "s2": "...",
    "pwd-script": "npx @bazel/bazelisk run //tools/ci:pwd_script_py -- --root-dir=$(pwd)"
    "start:all": "s1 && s2 && pwd-script",
  },
  ...
}
```

when I run `yarn start:all` or `yarn pwd-script`, the scripts break as `root-dir` evaluates to literal string `$(pwd)` instead of `C:\path\to\repo`

Environment:

- Win 11
- Win Terminal -> Git Bash
- node 16.14.1
- npm 8.5

This setup seems to be working fine in Linux & OSX environments, but I also need to get it working under Windows env

Also, it is not easily done to move that $(pwd) into the underlying python script as the script is being run in a sandbox.

Comment: well, npm script is execed as is without any shell capabilities, so it will just invoke something similar to `'echo' '$(pwd)'`. if you want shell capablities, in this case the processing of `$(...)`, one solution is to do `sh -c 'echo $(pwd)'`